# Xdvi to Emacs inverse search not working in Emacs 24.3.1 / AucTeX-11.87 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search, dvi

I'm trying to use AUCTeX to write my LaTeX documents. However I'm having issues with performing inverse search from Xdvi to Emacs.

*Software Specifications*

I currently use *Emacs 24.3.1 / AUCTeX-11.87 in Ubuntu 12.04.*

- The Emacs was downloaded and installed from [ppa:Cassou](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) and
  installed using their recommended commands.
- The AUCTeX-11.87 was downloaded from the AUCTeX website which was
  then configured (using just `./configure`) and installed (using
  `make`) inside the `~/.emacs.d` folder.

The following AUCTeX environment was set in the init file (`~/.emacs`).

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auctex-11.87")
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)

;; Inverse DVI Search
(tex-dvi-view-command "xdvi -editor 'emacsclient -a emacs --no-wait +%l %f'")
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'source-specials)
;;(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'SyncTeX)  ;; auctex 10.86  

(TeX-source-correlate-mode)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)

;;(TeX-source-correlate-mode)  
;;(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("View" "%V" TeX-run-discard nil t))

;;update the dvi file after each successful compilation
(add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style 
        '("^dvi$" "." 
          "%(o?)xdvi -watchfile 1 %dS %d"))
```

*Issues*

The most important issues that I have are

- Inspite of the environment specification, the `TeX-source-correlate-mode` is not automatically enabled when I open a `.tex` file. I need to enable it every time employing <kbd>C-c C-t C-s</kbd> command.
- The source special is not attached by AUCTeX automatically when I compile the `.tex` file using `Command -> LaTeX` option. Because when I open the `.dvi` ouput using xdvi, it complains to me stating the following Warning  *No source specials in this DVI file - couldn't do reverse search*.

The source specials do get attached to the dvi file if I just perform the following command line option

```
latex --src-specials main.tex
```

It will be of help if someone can help me identify the mistake I'm making in trying to create an inverse search from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to activate `TeX-source-correlate-mode` setting the option with the same name to non-nil.

Here is a working (for me) `.emacs` based on your:

```lisp
(setq tex-dvi-view-command "xdvi -editor 'emacsclient -a emacs --no-wait +%l %f'")
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     ;;update the dvi file after each successful compilation
     (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
          '("^dvi$" "."
            "%(o?)xdvi -watchfile 1 %dS %d"))
     (setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t
       TeX-auto-save t
       TeX-parse-self t
       reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t
       ;; Activate TeX-source-correlate-mode
       TeX-source-specials-mode t
       ;; Inverse DVI Search
       TeX-source-correlate-method 'source-specials)
     (setq-default TeX-master nil)
     (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
           (lambda
         (visual-line-mode)
         (flyspell-mode)
         (LaTeX-math-mode)
         (turn-on-reftex)))))
```

Comment: Although I solved this issue before I saw this comment, your .emacs looks better than mine and for that reason I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this issue by debugging by init file with the command

```
emacs --debug-init
```

Based on debugging I compiled the preview subfolder under AucTeX and also loaded its path. I also made other changes to the .emacs file as follows

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auctex-11.87")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auctex-11.87/preview")

(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'source-specials)

(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
```

Further I also ensured that emacs is the default editor for xdvi by adding the  the following export command to *~/.bashrc*

```
export XEDITOR="emacsclient --alternate-editor=emacs --no-wait +%l %f"
```

The AucTeX is now able to do inverse search seamlessly from Xdvi to Emacs.